# Java Swing PrivilegedActionException when trying to open wmv file

Tags: java, windows, swing, security, native

I'm using the java `Desktop` class to try to launch a video with its native application, and the code that launches it is:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(myVideoFile);
```

The video file is a wmv file, but whenever I try to launch it, I get the following exception

```
Unexpected Error


Message:
    java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.io.IOException: Failed to open file:/C:/Users/me/desktop/video.wmv. Error message: Unspecified error
Level:
    SEVERE
Stack Trace:
null
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:618)
    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
null
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:621)
    java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:619)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:618)
    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Failed to open file:/C:/Users/me/desktop/video.wmv. Error message: Unspecified error
    sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.ShellExecute(WDesktopPeer.java:59)
    sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.open(WDesktopPeer.java:36)
    java.awt.Desktop.open(Desktop.java:254)
    java_awt_Desktop$open.call(Unknown Source)
```

Opening a jpg file using the same code works. Any thoughts on what to do here?

Comment: What (if anything) do you get if you try/catch the statement and call `.getCause()` on the exception? Also, have you checked the read/write privileges on the file in question?

Comment: The cause is null, and the permissions are ok on the file.

Comment: That `PrivilegedActionException` seems suspicious to me.  What exactly is calling this code?  Is it operating in an environment where it has a Java based `SecurityManager`?

Comment: `PrivilegedActionException` just wraps checked exceptions for `AccessController.doPrivileged`.

Comment: The code is being called from a mouse listener on a jtable

Comment: The `Desktop.open` would fail if there are not sufficient permissions to read the file.

Comment: I verified and I do have permissions.